How to Copy Text Url in Filament Laravel
I'm using Laravel Filament and encountering an issue. I have multiple kits allocated to vendors, and I'm displaying the kit names with slug URLs. How can I copy only the URL without copying any other text?
public static function infolist(Infolist $infolist): Infolist
    {
        return $infolist
            ->schema([
                Components\Section::make()
                    ->schema([
                        Components\Split::make([
                            Components\Grid::make()
                                ->schema([
                                    Components\TextEntry::make('vendor.name'),
                                    Components\TextEntry::make('kit_ids')->label('Kits Name & URL')
                                    ->formatStateUsing(function (KitAllocation $kitAllocation) {
                                        $kitIds = $kitAllocation->kit_ids;
                                        $kits = Kit::whereIn('id', $kitIds)->get();
                                        $output = '';
                                        foreach ($kits as $kit) {
                                         $url = env('APP_URL') . ('/' . $kitAllocation->vendor->slug . '/' . $kit->slug);
                                         $output .= "<li>" . $kit->kit_name . "<br>" . ' -> ' . $url . "</li>";
                                        }
                                        return $output;
                                    })->html()
                                        ->copyable(function (KitAllocation $kitAllocation) {
                                            $kitIds = $kitAllocation->kit_ids;
                                            $kits = Kit::whereIn('id', $kitIds)->get();

                                            if ($kits->isNotEmpty()) {
                                                $kit = $kits->first();
                                                return env('APP_URL') . ('/' . $kitAllocation->vendor->slug . '/' . $kit->slug);
                                            }

                                            return '';
                                        }),

                                ]),

                        ])->from('lg'),
                    ]),

            ]);
    }

I want a data display like this "**Welcome T-shirt & Bag Pack Kits -> http://127.0.0.1:8000/olio-global-adtech/welcome-t-shirt-bag-pack-kits**" and copy only url on particular click text.
How to Copy only url in filament in multiple kits with url.
Any One help me on this.

To achieve this, you can use the copyableState() method to customize the text that is copied to the clipboard. See code below.
...
->html()
->copyable()
->copyableState(
  function (KitAllocation $record) {
     $kitAllocation = $record;
     $kitIds = $kitAllocation->kit_ids;
     $kits = Kit::whereIn('id', $kitIds)->get();
    
     if ($kits->isNotEmpty()) {
          $kit = $kits->first();
          return env('APP_URL') . ('/' . $kitAllocation->vendor->slug . '/' . $kit->slug);
     }
    
     return '';
  }),
...

Docs

Thanks, its working i forget about state, but i have one more issue is copy only first url. I have a url list using loop and i want to copy url on click on any url. can you help me @Didwiz

@PradeepKumar You may need to post another question with the appropriate code snippets relating to what you just asked me, so it's easier to address your new question, also if my answer wholly solves your question kindly accept it.
